# Shuffle objects in PHP

Tags: php, object, shuffle

How can I sort an object in PHP? I tried `shuffle()` but that expects an array:

```
Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, 
object given in /var/www/index.php on line 366

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/index.php on line 334
```

This is my code:

```
public function updateStatusWithoutDB() {
    $this->updateProfileColors();
    $items = $this->getItems();
    $items = shuffle($items);
    if($this->updateStatusArray($items))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

A `var_dump($items);` returns this:

```
["180"]=>
    object(stdClass)#203 (1) {
      ["status"]=>
      string(130) "I was checking Microsoft's Visual Studio page just no…"
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Sort an object"? The concept doesn't make any sense.

Comment: hmm.. how can i explain, a container of object should be randomly sorted

Comment: You mean you want to sort an array of objects?

Comment: @streetparade: are you looking to sort a collection of objects?

Comment: yes i want to sort an collection of objects

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot sort an object, since there is no order in the attributes.

However, you can sort an array representation of an object:

```
$arr = (array)$object;

shuffle($arr);
```

Comment: would be posible to acces objects the? like $obj->myvar ?

Comment: if you casted the $arr back to an object, then yes. $obj = (object) $arr;  would work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using $items as an array, either make `$this->getItems()` return an array or use `get_object_vars($items)` to get array of object's vars.