# Selecting random item from object

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a ini file like this:

```
[hints]
menu.0 = "Hint: Dropping a element on parent element will move the selected element at the end of list!"
menu.1 = "Hint: Use Menu elements to beautify your navigator!"
menu.2 = "Hint: Pages in red means they are draft pages. Adding them to your menu means that your visitors can not see the page!"
```

and reading the ini file using Zend_Config_Ini:

```
self::$hints = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/hints.ini',
                                      'hints');
```

The output on `var_dump(self::$hints->menu);` is:

```
object(Zend_Config)[63]
  protected '_allowModifications' => boolean false
  protected '_index' => int 0
  protected '_count' => int 3
  protected '_data' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Hint: Dropping a element on parent element will move the selected element at the end of list!' (length=93)
      1 => string 'Hint: Use Menu elements to beautify your navigator!' (length=51)
      2 => string 'Hint: Pages in red means they are draft pages. Adding them to your menu means that your visitors can not see the page!' (length=118)
  protected '_skipNextIteration' => null
  protected '_loadedSection' => null
  protected '_extends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_loadFileErrorStr' => null
```

I need help on randomly picking one item from that object and display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This PHP function can be useful for you:

```
array_rand();
```

Reference: [array_rand() in PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

As it is an object, you can previously do:

```
$arr = (array)$object;
```

as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1897695/2228023

Comment: Yes, thanks that should solve it. Only one issue I have more, I don't know how to access the _data from that object as it is protected, any idea ?

Comment: You can create a `getData()` method and call it.

Comment: I doubt that isn't one in ZF already... if I would name the data inside the object "menu.one" I could access it with self::$hints->menu->one but I have a 0 there and self::$hints->menu->0 or self::$hints->menu[0] doesn't work...

Comment: Solved it by using:
$toArray = $hints->menu->toArray();
$randomKey = array_rand($toArray);
  
return $toArray[$randomKey];